# Mock an Item in Nunit having fast Query

Tags: unit-testing

I have a fast query :

> /sitecore/content/Countries/*

I tried to mock them using nunit as

```
using (Db db = new Db()
            {

                new DbItem("Countries"){
                    new DbItem("India"){

                 },
                new DbItem("South Africa"){

                 },
                },
            })
```

But it returns only the empty Item.It is not taking India and Africa.Suggest some ways to Mock those Items.

Comment: Could you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Using a fast:// query to query child items of Countries?  Seriously?

Answer (score 5):

When writing unit tests for Sitecore my general rule of thumb is to try not to test whether it's doing its job, that's not your responsibility.

I think you might be better off abstracting this away behind some interface. From your question, I can only assume that you have some consumer that is using a list of countries in some way. If you define an interface whose responsibility is to get a list of countries.

```
interface ICountries
{
    IEnumerable<Country> GetAllCountries();
}

class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can then pass this in as a constructor argument of the consumer

```
class CountriesConsumer 
{
    ICountries _countries;
    CountriesConsumer(ICountries countries)
    {
        _countries = countries;
    }

    DoSomethign()
    {
        _countries.GetAllCountries();
    }
}
```

I prefer this approach as then all I need to do is mock my own focused interface and let Sitecore just do its thing.

Answer (score 3):

As I stated in comments, it's a good practice to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For this particular case, it seems everything works fine so I need more details to reproduce your issue. If I create a test like this, it passes (NUnit 3.10.1):

```
[Test]
public void QueryTest()
{
    using (var db = new Db
    {
        new DbItem("Countries")
        {
            new DbItem("India"),
            new DbItem("South Africa")
        }
    })
    {
        var selectItems = db.Database.SelectItems("fast://sitecore/content/Countries/*");
        Assert.Equal(2, selectItems.Length); // Pass
    }
}
```

Please take a note that [FastQuery support is limited in FakeDb](https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/issues/182).